# ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::InvalidTextRepresentation: ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer: ""

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql-9.1

rails - 5.2

```
MyModel.order("(data ->> 'position')::Integer ASC").each {|x| puts x.position}
```

I am getting following error

> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::InvalidTextRepresentation: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: ""

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: the `data` payload might not exists yet, or might not have the 'position' key yet, so you ask pg to cast it

Comment: it does not even work in plain SQL query

Comment: That's not the point I was trying to bring to the table; you might not want to cast something that does not exists yet. Do you have a position key in your meta field for every records ?

Comment: you are quite correct on that point. There were some of them with null values. Thx for direction